A matrix with anything?
I am looking for a way to control how hot a surface is using Peltier tiles. I had decided upon using a matrix of them (10 by 10 matrix to be specific). I know that by using shift registers I can control an 8 by 8 led matrix. Can something like that be used in my application, and to be more specific can I use a shift register to control a matrix using any output device?

for sensing temperature, perhaps you could use a IR camera or something like this. Depends of the surface to be "scanned".

Yes. Most shift registers have low output current capability, which may be sufficient for an LED, but not for a heating element, for instance. For higher-power loads you would need to employ transistors to take care of switching the higher currents, but the matrix arrangement is still appropriate:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
P-Channel MOSFETs (or PNP bipolar transistors) M1, M2 and M3 connect/disconnect load anodes to/from the positive supply. They are controlled by signals ROW1, ROW2 and ROW3 from a digital register (see caveat below). A low ROW signal switches its transistor on.
N-Channel MOSFETs (or NPN bipolar transistors) M4, M5 and M6 connect/disconnect the cathodes to/from 0V. A high COL signal switches its transistor ON.
To switch on load X23, ROW2=low and COL3=high.
If the positive supply used by the loads is the same as the register ICs, say +5V, then the above is sufficient. The caveat is that if the loads require a higher potential positive supply (say +12V) than the register ICs (+5V) then the ROW signals will need to be translated from 0V/+5V to 0V/+12V, which would require one additional transistor for each row.
Using this scheme, an 8 × 8 matrix would require a total of 16 (or 24) transistors.
If you need to control current in both directions through the loads, which is hinted at by your suggestion of using peltier devices, then this single-transistor-per-row/column solution won't be sufficient. That would require a much more complex arrangement of transistors.

why do i need different mosfets for the column/rows

N-channel to sink current to ground, P-channel to source current from positive supply. That's just a limitation of MOSFETs in general. There are other solutions, it is possible to use N-channel in both roles, but that introduces more issues to address.

Note that this will not work if you need more than one element turned on at a time. For fully general control of this 8x8 matrix you would need a full set of 64 transistors. Multiplexing like you can do with LEDs isn't likely to work all that well for heaters.

Yeah using 100 bits worth of shift registers turning 100 peltiers on or off.
You might still need 100 sesnors to figure out if the temperature is right in each location,  might need more bits if you need more than on/off control etc.
in the end it may be easier to deploy 100 cheap microcontrollers each controlling the on/off of the peltiers (via a MOSFET) and checking the temperature using a thermistor or a TMP103

Also implied you will need a way to take a logic level signal and use it to control the high-current load of a peltier x100. And a power supply and distribution network capable of powering everything which at that scale is not trivial.

for sensing temperature, do i use a thermistor (which one) or is there another way

and how will it do it
